# WCF: Inspecting response content length

Tags: .net, wcf

How can one hook into this info?

I need to do some auditing, and while it is rather trivial to handle the request info, the response info seems to elude me.

Currently, I can only view this info locally via Fiddler or Wireshark (and I dont really feel like running Wireshark on the server).

Thanks

Comment: A suppose you can write your own trace listener for the [WCF Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) but I have not really tried myself. I have only traced relevant info to file for offline viewing.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: Thanks, will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it using [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) ?

**MSDN Info:-**

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   Service Trace Viewer Tool helps you
>   analyze diagnostic traces that are
>   generated by WCF. Service Trace Viewer
>   provides a way to easily merge, view,
>   and filter trace messages in the log
>   so that you can diagnose, repair, and
>   verify WCF service issues.